# Why the printf is working within the fgets() function, but not anywhere else?

Tags: c, fgets

I'm currently doing exercises from Stephan Prata book called "C Primer Plus" and I'm on chapter 11 which is all about strings.
I have code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 10
int main (void)
{
    char word[SIZE];
    int i; 

    puts("Enter the string(empty string ends the program):");
    while (fgets(word, SIZE, stdin) != NULL && word[0] != '\n')
    {
        i = 0;
        while (word[i] != '\n' && word[i] != '\0')
            i++;
        if (word[i] == '\n')
            word[i] = '\0';
        else
            while (getchar() != '\n')
                continue;
        printf("%s", word); // function X
    }
    printf("%s", word); // function Y

    return 0;
}
```

Output looks like this:

```
Enter the string(empty string ends the program):
Star Wars <- string I entered
Star Wars <- output from function X
          <- empty string I entered
```

And my question is like this: why the printf is working correctly on the line 19, and don't work in line 21?

Comment: Look at the condition in the while loop. If the loop just exited, then that condition must be false. What do you expect to be printed when the condition is false?

Comment: I entered the empty string and printf() (function Y) does not input anything at all.

Comment: Did you expect anything ese? If so, what exactly? If not, what us the question?

Comment: Yes, I excepted that after I write "Star Wars" that string will be put into array, and after I end program by entering the empty string, the "Star Wars" string will still be in that array.

Comment: You did not enter an empty string. You can't do that. You entered an *empty line*. An empty line is a string that consists solely of an `'\n'` character. When you enter a line, empty or not, it ends up in your array, overwriting what previously was there.

Comment: Oh, I understand know. Thank you for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed an interesting point about what an *empty string* is.

On first pass you enter 10 characters : `S t a r blank W a r s \n`. `fgets` put 9 in the `word` buffer followed by the terminating null, and you read the end of line with your `getchar` loop. Then you correctly write `Star Wars` with no end of line in the `printf` at line 19.

If you enter a newline here, `fgets` will write 2 characters in `word`: the `\n` and a terminating null. As `word[0]` is `'\n'`, the loop exits, and the `printf`  at line 21 successfully outputs the newline character, giving a blank line on the terminal window.

Things would be more funny if you entered an end of file mark (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> on an Unix-like system, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>z</kbd> or <kbd>F6</kbd> on Windows). Because `fgets` would not change anything in the `word` array, and the `printf` of line 21 would repeat the previous value. On my Windows console, it gives:

```
Enter the string(empty string ends the program):
Star Wars
Star Wars^Z
Star Wars
```

Answer (score 0):

> I excepted that after I write "Star Wars" that string will be put into array, and after I end program by entering the empty string, the "Star Wars" string will still be in that array.

You overlook that *by entering the empty string*, *that string will be put into* `word`, and exactly that *empty string* is printed in *printf() (function Y)*.